# how can I build a flag set from arrays in Postgresql?

Tags: arrays, postgresql

Is there a way to make a flag set from two arrays in Postgresql?
What I want is something like:

```
array1[] = {'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd'}
array2[] = {'aa', 'cc'}

result[] = {'aa', '--', 'cc', '--'}
```

It should be easy if just an intersection, but I need explicit "no commons", too.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select array_agg(case 
                when a1.id is null or a2.id is null then '--'
                else a1.id
             end)  
from unnest(array['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd']) as a1(id)
  left join unnest(array['aa', 'cc']) as a2(id) on a1.id = a2.id
```

Comment: uh-huh!   the scales fell from my eyes!  thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I have this:

```
SELECT
    array_agg(flag_value)
FROM (
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN array_value = ANY (ARRAY['aa', 'cc']) THEN
            array_value
        ELSE
            '--'
        END AS flag_value
    FROM
        unnest(ARRAY['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd']) AS array_value
) AS X;
```

Comment: your approach is as clear as a_horse_with_no_name.  though his answer seems to show slightly deeper thought, your answer is also good enough for my purpose.  thank you for prompt answer!